# SQLite join a single column into multiple columns in another table and select

Tags: sqlite

I have two (simplified) tables:

`TriggerSensor`:

```
id INTEGER
active INTEGER
```

`TriggerLogic`:

```
programId INTEGER
ts1 INTEGER
ts2 INTEGER
ts3 INTEGER
ts4 INTEGER
```

The ts1 to ts4 columns contain the id from `TriggerSensor` table.

So, by adding `TriggerLogic` rows I create programs with different sensor setups.

Is it possible to make a

```
SELECT programId 
FROM TriggerLogic 
WHERE [all triggers are active]?
```

Something like

```
SELECT programId 
FROM TriggerLogic l 
INNER JOIN TriggerSensor s ON l.ts1 = s.id 
                           AND l.ts2 = s.id 
                           AND l.ts3 = s.id 
                           AND l.ts4 = s.id
WHERE s.active = 1
```

but where the result only returns rows where all four `s.active=1`?

The `SELECT` above returns no rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the `TriggerSensor` table 4 times

```
SELECT programId 
FROM TriggerLogic l 
INNER JOIN TriggerSensor s1 ON l.ts1 = s1.id AND s1.active = 1
INNER JOIN TriggerSensor s2 ON l.ts2 = s2.id AND s2.active = 1
INNER JOIN TriggerSensor s3 ON l.ts3 = s3.id AND s3.active = 1
INNER JOIN TriggerSensor s4 ON l.ts4 = s4.id AND s4.active = 1
```